# Button is going behind header

Tags: debugging

I have a Login and Register button and it goes behind the header and I don't know how to fix it here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHiEe.jpg Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code. It can be wrong div placement or position option or padding. Hard to guess from image.

Comment: here is the Login and register  
    <div class="mav">
        <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: css: .mav li {
    float: right;
    padding: 22px;
    margin-top: -17px;
}


.mav li {
    float: right;
    padding: 22px;
    margin-top: -59px;
}

Comment: Context is missing, but the css looks a bit messy. I would use one div for both or two different names. Then I would think about setting type of positioning: relative or absolute and then what is the dependency of header div and login div.

Comment: the position is fixed and when I take that off, It works but I need the position to be fixed any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to truly help without being able to see or inspect the code. Just from looking at the image it looks like your header position is either absolute of fixed. If so, you need to add a top margin to the main content of the same amount of pixels as the height of the header.

Comment: Well, When I do that the button goes behind the header.. The header is Fixed.

Comment: Well, you need post your code in fiddle or codepen or something or send the link to the website. I can't help you without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Make header fixed and this login absolute to it. It should work.

Fixed header will keep it on same place during scrolling. Absolute inside will kerp it aligned with header. So it should stay too.